# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function Workaround

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g

```
select
        o.customer_id,
        c.cust_first_name,
        c.cust_last_name,
        c.income_level,
        to_char(o.order_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH12:MI') as order_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.order_date) as order#,
        o.order_total,
        lag(o.order_total, 1, 0) over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.customer_id) 
        + lag(o.order_total, 2, 0) over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.customer_id) as last_two_orders_sum,
        min(o.order_date) keep (dense_rank last order by o.customer_id) as first_order_total
from orders o, customers c
where o.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

This is my query which produces this error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

**Expected result for the last column - first order of every customer:**

[image: expected results screenshot]

I know that I have to use GROUP BY clause to handle this error, but it seems rather inappropriate to group by all the other columns.. I know that this is a limitation in Oracle 11g and this issue is fixed in 12c, but I still need some kind of workaround.

**Tried:**

CTEs --> kinda weird to have single select in a CTE

Subquery --> can't figure out the right syntax and it produces a mess

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please add a [mre] with all tables and with data ideally as dbfiddle, a group function will always produce only 1 row withoout a group by, so uise a group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than the `MIN(...) KEEP (...)` aggregation function, you want to use `MIN(...) KEEP (...) OVER (...)` analytic function or, possibly without the `KEEP`, use `MIN(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)`:

```sql
select
        o.customer_id,
        c.cust_first_name,
        c.cust_last_name,
        c.income_level,
        to_char(o.order_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH12:MI') as order_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.order_date)
          as order#,
        o.order_total,
        lag(o.order_total, 1, 0)
          over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.customer_id) 
        + lag(o.order_total, 2, 0)
          over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.customer_id)
          as last_two_orders_sum,
        MIN(o.order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) as first_order_date,
        MIN(o.order_total) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY o.order_date)
                           OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id) as first_order_total
from    orders o
        INNER JOIN customers c
        ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

*Note: Also, use ANSI join syntax rather than the legacy comma-join syntax.*

> I know that this is a limitation in Oracle 11g and this issue is fixed in 12c, but I still need some kind of workaround.

No, this is not something that you fix by upgrading to a later version. It is a fundamental issue with your query that you are using an mix of aggregated and non-aggregated columns and, as the error message implies, you do not have a `GROUP BY` clause that includes all of the non-aggregated columns.

The solution is to not use any aggregation functions and change to only use analytic functions.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ab0311b051d7bd40f0b53178f1aab4ee)*

Comment: dbfiddle helped a lot. Thank you!